# Impossible to get CRS with tomcat : org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException

Tags: java, tomcat, geotools

I'm having a weird situation.
I use geotools to project rasters and it works for example

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857");

GridCoverage2D projectedImage = (GridCoverage2D) Operations.DEFAULT.resample(gridCoverageImage,
                        targetCRS);
```

Now I moved my process in a web server controller with the exact same code :

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getProjectedImage(@RequestParam 
String filename, @RequestParam String targetCrs){
     File file = new File(filename);
     CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode(targetCrs);
     /** Some process to return file /**
}
```

I'm having :

```
org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:3857"
from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS"
```

My pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-coverage</artifactId>
        <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
        <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-image</artifactId>
        <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-wms</artifactId>
        <version>18.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I look into WEB-INF/lib, all jars are here including dependencies (gt-referencing, gt-metadata.....)

Tomcat : 8.0
Java 8
GeoTools : 18.2

It works fine when I'm not in a servlet container.
Also, other utilities from geotools are working fine. For example, the cropping or the GridCoverage2D conversion work in this servlet container.

Could you please help me understand what's going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any Idea ? I tried with different calls 
`Hints hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
CRSAuthorityFactory factory = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory("EPSG", hints);`

And then `CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = factory.createGeographicCRS(responseCrs.trim());`  ==> Same Error

Comment: does tomcat have write permission to `java.io.tempdir`?

Comment: Yes it does, can you explain why would that be an issue ? and the relation between epsg-hsql and java.io.tempdir ? thanks

Comment: Geotools unpacks the epsg database there

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir.
Actually, after investigations it does not. So it maybe the problem comes from here. I tested with a File.createTempFile(...) and I have `Access Denied`
Would you know how to make it default that tomcat can access java.io.tmpdir ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is most likely that Tomcat (or the user running it) doesn't have write permission to `java.io.tmpdir` which is where GeoTools unpacks the H2 EPSG database to when it first looks up an EPSG code.

You can either change the permissions on the temp directory to allow tomcat to write there or you can change the location it uses by changing the `CATALINA_TMPDIR` variable in `catalina.sh` or `catalina.bat`, or simply add `Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\{yourDir}` to your startup script.

This [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/13523/configure-tomcat-to-use-a-different-temp-directory-for-file-uploads) also has some answers that may help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround even if it doesn't solve the initial issue (related to dependencies of geotools and the deployement into Tomcat)

don't use gt-epsg-hsql which leads your app searching for the EPSG code to decode into the HSQL database.

Rather than using `CRS.decode(targetCrs);`
with

```
CRS.parseWKT("PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / Plate Carree (deprecated)\",\r\n" + 
                "    GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",\r\n" + 
                "        DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",\r\n" + 
                "            SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\r\n" + 
                "                AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],\r\n" + 
                "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],\r\n" + 
                "        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\r\n" + 
                "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],\r\n" + 
                "        UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\r\n" + 
                "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],\r\n" + 
                "        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],\r\n" + 
                "    PROJECTION[\"Equirectangular\"],\r\n" + 
                "    UNIT[\"metre\",1,\r\n" + 
                "        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],\r\n" + 
                "    AXIS[\"X\",EAST],\r\n" + 
                "    AXIS[\"Y\",NORTH],\r\n" + 
                "    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"32662\"]]");
```

You can find all WKT related to every EPSG code  [here](https://epsg.io/3857)

If someone has an answer or an explanation to the original issue, i'd love to read it :)